# Projection math in software 3d engine

Tags: javascript, opengl, math, 3d, rendering

I'm working on writing a software 3d engine in Javascript, rendering to 2d canvas. I'm totally stuck on an issue related to the projection from 3d world to 2d screen coordinates.

### So far, I have:

- A camera Projection and View matrix.
- Transformed Model vertices (v x ModelViewProj).
- Take the result and divide both the x and y by the z (perspective) coordinate, making viewport coords.
- Scale the resultant 2d vector by the viewport size.

I'm drawing a plane, and everything works when all 4 vertices (2 tris) are on screen. When I fly my camera over the plane, at some point, the off screen vertices transform to the top of the screen. That point seems to coincide with when the perspective coordinate goes above 1. I have an example of what i mean here - press forward to see it flip:

http://davidgoemans.com/phaser3d/

Code isn't minified, so web dev tools can inspect easily, but i've also put the source here:

https://github.com/dgoemans/phaser3dtest/tree/fixcanvas

Thanks in advance!

---

note: I'm using phaser, not really to do anything at the moment, but my plan is to mix 2d and 3d. It shouldn't have any effect on the 3d math.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When projection points which lie behind of the virtual camera, the results will be projected in front of it, mirrored. `x/z` is just the same as `-x/-z`.

In rendering pipelines, this problem is addresses by *clipping algorithms* which intersect the primitives by clipping planes. In your case, a single clipping plane which lies somewhere in front of your camera, is enough (in rendering pipelines, one is usually using 6 clipping planes to describe a complete viewing volume). You must prevent the situation that a single primitive has at least one point on front of the camera, and at least another one behind it (and you must discard primitives which lie completely behind, but that is rather trivial). Clipping must be done before the perspective divide, which is also the reason why the space the projection matrix transforms to is called the *clip space*.

Comment: thanks! is this something that openGL/DirectX normally does for you? I come from a hardware 3d background, and i don't recall ever running into this, so just wondering :)

Comment: Yes. It is actually something the GPUs do for you.

Comment: got some time to try the suggested Z clipping, and works like a charm. Thanks! :)